# mail server while using from outlook gives this error 0x80042109

Tags: email, mdaemon

We are using mdamemon as our mail server and we are hosting it ourselves. Since last few days, i am having problems to send mail using outlook as it takes longer time than before and gives this error 0x80042109. While i use world Client,which is web mail, there are no problems at all.
While i try resolving it, i found the following errors from the log :
"Connection timed out! SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out: 6028/585)"

Is there a way to look into these errors? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK 0x80042109 means Outlook just cannot connect to your SMTP server.
See SMTP settings in Outlook and check connectivity to that host / IP and port (e.g. with telnet).

Comment: i can't telnet to my domain. telnet mail.abc.com 25 says Could not open connection to the host, on port 25. Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: Try telnet to internal ip of mdaemon, then external ip.
Check nslookup for mail.abc.com
Check mdaemon settings for SMTP-port.
Check firewalls between your PC and mdaemon.

Comment: now i can telnet to mail.abc.com on port 587 but can't telnet on port 25. The network vendor says there is nothing wrong with firewall. We have used 25 as smtp port and haven't used authentication. After, using 587 and even after using authentication, it didn't work.

Comment: Not being able to connect to port 25 is the problem. As Vadim asked, are you able to do so from inside the network to your mailserver's local IP? IF so, then there's a networking problem, possibly with the firewall but not definitely.